# Creating a VectorDrawable from an SVG file at runtime

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I want to create an VectorDrawable from a **remote SVG file** (ie a URL), within my app (not in Android Studio). After a bit of searching, I have yet to find a way to do this programmatically, is there even a way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way? Can you describe your use case? Perhaps we can suggest an alternate solution to your original problem.

Comment: I have similar case where I need to create menu items at run time and I want to have text and images.

Answer (score -1):

First yo need to download the resource like a file or InputStream class type.

After that, you must transform to a graphic class. To do that I found this library: [Library tutorial](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg)

Good Luck!

Comment: Where's the part you convert to VectorDrawable?